# Trying to Indent in Algorithm Mode

Tags: spacing, algorithms, algorithmic

I'm trying to indent in `\usepackage{algorithm}` mode, but it's not working.

I need to use `\usepackage{algorithm}` because of journal as there are other answers on this forum
that use other packages that do not apply here.

Can somebody help me with this...thanks...
[image]

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Analytically computing $X_{1:n}$}
\label{analcomputex1n}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function{ComputeMinimum}{$n,  \widetilde{\bm{p}},  \widetilde{\bm{B}},  \widetilde{\bm{Y}} $}
%\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}$
\State $\bm{B}_n \gets \underbrace{ \widetilde{\bm{B}} \otimes \widetilde{\bm{B}} \otimes \dots \otimes \widetilde{\bm{B}}}_{\mbox{$n$ times}}$
\State $\bm{V}_n = \bm{B}^{-1}_n$
\State $k \gets 1$
\State $X_{1:n} \gets 0$
\For{$i_1 \gets 1, n$}
    \For{$i_2 \gets 1, n$}
            \State $\cdots$
                \For{$i_n \gets 1, n$}
                    \State $X_{1:n}  \gets X_{1:n}  +  \bm{\wp}_o[1,i_1]$  \newline 
                    \hspace{3cm} $\widetilde{\bm{Y}}[i_1,i_2] \widetilde{\bm{Y}}[i_2,i_{i_2+1}]$ \dots \newline
                    \hspace{3cm} $\widetilde{\bm{Y}}[i_{n-1},i_{i_n}]\bm{V}_n[k,k]$
                    \State $k \gets k + 1$
                \EndFor
            \State $\cdots$
    \EndFor
\EndFor
\State \Return  $X_{1:n}$
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\hspace*` should solve the problem. I have left your `3cm`. The exact value is your choice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{algorithmicx}
 
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
 \def\bm#1{\boldmath{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Analytically computing $X_{1:n}$}
\label{analcomputex1n}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function{ComputeMinimum}{$n,  \widetilde{\bm{p}},  \widetilde{\bm{B}},  \widetilde{\bm{Y}} $}
%\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}$
\State $\bm{B}_n \gets \underbrace{ \widetilde{\bm{B}} \otimes \widetilde{\bm{B}} \otimes \dots \otimes \widetilde{\bm{B}}}_{\mbox{$n$ times}}$
\State $\bm{V}_n = \bm{B}^{-1}_n$
\State $k \gets 1$
\State $X_{1:n} \gets 0$
\For{$i_1 \gets 1, n$}
    \For{$i_2 \gets 1, n$}
            \State $\cdots$
                \For{$i_n \gets 1, n$}
                    \State $X_{1:n}  \gets X_{1:n}  +  \bm{\wp}_o[1,i_1]$  \newline 
                    \hspace*{3cm} $\widetilde{\bm{Y}}[i_1,i_2] \widetilde{\bm{Y}}[i_2,i_{i_2+1}]$ \dots \newline
                    \hspace*{3cm} $\widetilde{\bm{Y}}[i_{n-1},i_{i_n}]\bm{V}_n[k,k]$
                    \State $k \gets k + 1$
                \EndFor
            \State $\cdots$
    \EndFor
\EndFor
\State \Return  $X_{1:n}$
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
  
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works! Thanks for your help.